# synchronization between SQL local db and MYSQL on server

Tags: c#, mysql, django, localdb

I have Desktop Application with SQL local DB and Web app with Django and mysql Database whats the best method to sync the local clients which is more than 50 user with only oner server and its mysql which method work perfect in this section

Comment: How many databases, of which sort, do you have? Please share a bit more about your problem.

Comment: Hi on each client there is one database with daily records of between 50 to 500 records

Comment: So, you have 50 times (for every user) a SQL local DB (with 50-500 records), and one (central) MySQL database ?  sound like you could write a webservice to push the records to the server, and get new records (if that is needed). You only need 1 webservice, not 50.

Comment: so you say its better to use API for sync . what about the sync framework in .net ?

Comment: You did not provide enough information to comment on your last comment (about: "what about the sync framework in .net")

Comment: after this post i researched and found something about sync framework but i dont know its work with mysql or no or i have to use API

Comment: "Microsoft Sync Framework is a data synchronization platform from Microsoft ...., modelled on the ADO.NET data provider **API**"  ([Microsoft Sync Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework)), so you will be using an API when you use sync framework from .net.

Comment: thanks so its better to make my own api

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at a tool such as Symmetric DS

https://www.symmetricds.org/

Doing something like this on your own would require a lot of understanding and dealing with database transactions and fault protection etc.

Comment: Hi i saw this one but i dont want to install tools in each pc its need configuration my clients cant do this